# Cannot install .bin package on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, installation-package

I try to install clip2net application on Ubuntu 9.10 and get the error.

```
lyuba@lyuba-laptop:~/Desktop$ chmod a+x linux_clip2net01b_installer.bin
lyuba@lyuba-laptop:~/Desktop$ sudo linux_clip2net01b_installer.bin
[sudo] password for lyuba: 
sudo: linux_clip2net01b_installer.bin: command not found
```

What may cause the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unlikely that `~/Desktop` is in your path.

Did you try:

`sudo ./linux_clip2net01b_installer.bin`

(After the other steps mentioned)?

Comment: Actually, I resolved the problem by just running ./linux_clip2net01b_installer.bin. I didn't know that you have to put this ./ before the name of the file. Thanks!