# Unable to install bin files.(No such file or directory error)

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I wanted to install adobe reader on my ubuntu 10.10(Maverick Meerkat).I have downloaded the file and copied it on  my desktop.I had then browsed to the desktop directory through command line terminal.

I had tried all the possible combinations of the commands but still i get a "file or directory does not exist error"

> roger@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ chmod a+x AdbeRdr9.4-1_i486linux_enu.bin
>   roger@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ sudo ./AdbeRdr9.4-1_i486linux_enu.bin
>   sudo: unable to execute ./AdbeRdr9.4-1_i486linux_enu.bin: No such file or directory

I tried without the sudo and this is what i get

> roger@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ chmod a+x AdbeRdr9.4-1_i486linux_enu.bin
>   roger@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ ./AdbeRdr9.4-1_i486linux_enu.bin
>   bash: ./AdbeRdr9.4-1_i486linux_enu.bin: No such file or directory

The file is present in the desktop.Where am i going wrong?

P.S:This is not a duplicate of the question [Cannot install .bin package on Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/193787/cannot-install-bin-package-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does

```
file AdbeRdr9.4-1_i486linux_enu.bin
```

say?

Try

```
sudo bash AdbeRdr9.4-1_i486linux_enu.bin
```

Or are you on a 64-bit system?

Try installing the 32-bit compatibility libraries.

Comment: Thanks.I am not at home right now.I will check it in a few hours and get back.

Comment: Once i tried installing the 32 bit compatibility libraries i got this error-Errors were encountered while processing:
firmware-b43-installer , which was resolved with this solution-http://ubuntu-ky.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1674623(incase anybody needs it).After this the initial commands worked fine.But somehow the software didn't seem to be installed after that and the icon never appeared on the desktop although the command worked fine.Any comments on this? Anyway i have installed adobe reader through the ubuntu software center.Thanks a lot for helping me out :)